# using :not for the first child + every 3 therefore after

Tags: css, css-selectors

Trying to figure out how I can attack certain li's depending on position. Essentially, I need to `NOT` target either the first child, and then every 3 after.

Example:

```
li1 (dont target) | li4(dont target)  | li7 (dont target)
li2 (target)      | li5 (target)      | li8 (target)
li3 (target)      | li6 (target)      | li9 (target)
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

`.siteMapSubList.threecolumn > li:not(:nth-child(1n+3))`

the class name is irrelevant, as well as the css code I'm implementing, so I didn't include that. However, this doesn't work. As in, does not target the ones I'm trying to target. I'm REALLY trying to avoid having 2 different rules (having one not target the first child and then every 3 after) which I think I can do now. So I really want to do this in one rule, if possible.

**EDIT**

Want to make sure people understand what I need better. So essentially if we have 9 li's, I want to NOT target 1, 4 and 7. 2,3,5,6,8,9 I want to target (which is why I'm using a not operator, but if you have a better way, I'm all ears).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close! The selector you need is `li:not(:nth-child(3n+1))`.

See example below:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 6em;
}

li {
  height: 2em;
}

li:not(:nth-child(3n+1)) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: YES! This is perfect, thanks! (Ill accept when the time lets me :) )

Comment: Fun fact: n+3 would in fact be even closer had the items flown in rows and not columns as in the question - the selector would then be li:not(:nth-child(-n+3)), with a negative sign. Of course, it helps to pay close attention to the layout in situations like this.